# How to manage security and authentication in iOS programming for posting request and getting response?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7.1, ios8.1

I want to implement security and authentication when i am calling an API.
So that my data will not be lost and hijacked by some one in middle.I have searched so many times on net but there is no good article with example.Some one has asked to implement NSURLSession with AFNetworking.
I have used encryption with key before 2 years is there any new things to implement security with authentication when we make request and getting response(is there need of encoding and encryption?).
Please eleborate with suitable example.
what Type of suggestion i have to give also to API developer

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SSL ceritificates` (HTTPS) to avoid `man-in-middle attack`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to invent your own crypto. It is not recommended at all. You should use SSL. That will be good enough. Refer to this article
Refer to [this](http://www.programering.com/a/MzN1YDNwATM.html) article. In addition there are plenty of other examples in internet. Hope this helps